# Count unique values across columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to create a new variable with unique counts of string values from two different columns. So I have something like this, for example:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  names   partners                 
  <fct>   <fct>                    
1 John    Mary, Ashley, John, Kate 
2 Mary    Charlie, John, Mary, John
3 Charlie Kate, Marcy              
4 David   Mary, Claire
```

```
structure(list(names = structure(c(3L, 4L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Charlie", 
"David", "John", "Mary"), class = "factor"), partners = structure(c(3L, 
1L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("Charlie, John, Mary, John", "Kate, Marcy", 
"Mary, Ashley, John, Kate", "Mary, Claire"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
4L), class = "data.frame")
```

and I want to get something like this

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  names   partners                  uniquecounts
  <fct>   <fct>                            <dbl>
1 John    Mary, Ashley, John, Kate             4
2 Mary    Charlie, John, Mary, John            3
3 Charlie Kate, Marcy                          3
4 David   Mary, Claire                         3
```

I tried combining both columns in one and counting the unique values in that but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With`tidyverse`, first convert factor columns to character, use `map2` and split `partners` to individual vector of strings and then count unique values combining with `names` using `n_distinct`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate_all(as.character) %>%
  mutate(uniquecounts = map2_dbl(names, partners, 
                       ~ n_distinct(c(.x, str_split(.y, ", ")[[1]]))))


#    names                    partners uniquecounts
#1    John  Mary, Ashley, John, Kate            4
#2    Mary Charlie, John, Mary, John            3
#3 Charlie               Kate, Marcy            3
#4   David              Mary, Claire            3
```

---

With same logic in base R

```
df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)
as.numeric(mapply(function(x, y) length(unique(c(x, y))), 
          df$names, strsplit(df$partners, ", ")))
#[1] 4 3 3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

There's another way with `toString`.

```
dat$uniquecounts <- sapply(strsplit(apply(dat, 1, toString), ", "), 
                           function(x) length(unique(x)))

dat
#     names                  partners uniquecounts
# 1    John  Mary, Ashley, John, Kate            4
# 2    Mary Charlie, John, Mary, John            3
# 3 Charlie               Kate, Marcy            3
# 4   David              Mary, Claire            3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method using `tidyverse` without looping

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(partners = str_c(names, partners, sep=", ")) %>%
   separate_rows(partners) %>%
   distinct %>% 
   count(names) %>% 
   right_join(df1)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  names       n partners                 
#  <fct>   <int> <fct>                    
#1 John        4 Mary, Ashley, John, Kate 
#2 Mary        3 Charlie, John, Mary, John
#3 Charlie     3 Kate, Marcy              
#4 David       3 Mary, Claire
```