# Counting number of unique values within another column (id) in R

Tags: r, count

I saw similar posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38334777/count-unique-values-of-a-column-by-pairwise-combinations-of-another-column-in-r) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55649233/count-unique-values-across-columns-in-r) but they were not keeping all rows.
I have a dataset looks like this:

```
id <- c(1,1,1,1, 2,2,2)
item.id <- c(1,3,4,4, 2,1,1)
sequence <- c(1,1,1,2, 1,1,2)

data <- data.frame("id"=id, "item.id"=item.id, "sequence"=sequence)
> data
  id item.id sequence
1  1       1        1
2  1       3        1
3  1       4        1
4  1       4        2
5  2       2        1
6  2       1        1
7  2       1        2
```

`id` represents for each student, `item.id` represents the questions students take, `sequence` is the attempt number for each `item.id`.

For each `id`, I would like to count the number of unique `item.id`s per `id`. More importantly, I would  like to add this `item.count` variable to the data frame. Below is the desired output, keeping all rows and adding the count information for each `id`:

```
> data
  id item.id sequence  item.count
1  1       1        1    3
2  1       3        1    3
3  1       4        1    3
4  1       4        2    3
5  2       2        1    2
6  2       1        1    2
7  2       1        2    2
```

Any insights?
Thanks

Comment: `transform(data, count = ave(item.id, id, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))))`

Comment: if you want `dplyr`: `data %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(item.count = length(unique(item.id)))`

Comment: with `dplyr`, one can use `n_distinct(item.id)`